# Insert new data into specific table in a the database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, insert

I design a system and I want from the user firstly to choose from a combo box the name of the table he want to insert then he will enter the rest of the fields.. My question is that how can I let the user enter the name of the table using sql statement .. I write the following doesn't  but it doesn't work ??

```
 try { 
            Object service = Service_ComboBox.getSelectedItem(); 
            String ref = "0";  
            String title = title_TextField1.getText(); 
            Object riskRating = riskRating_ComboBox3.getSelectedItem();
            Object rootCause = rootCause_ComboBox4.getSelectedItem(); 
            Object impact = impact_ComboBox1.getSelectedItem(); 
            Object likelihood = likelihood_ComboBox2.getSelectedItem(); 
            String efforts = efforts_TextField7.getText(); 
            String finding = finding_TextField9.getText(); 
            String implication = implication_TextArea1.getText(); 
            String recommendation = recommendation_TextArea2.getText(); 

          Connection  conn= DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","SYSTEM","*******");
             String query = "insert into ? (Service,Ref,Title,Risk_Rating,Root_cause,Impact ,Likelihood,Efforts,Finding,Implication,Recommendation)values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?)"; 

         PreparedStatement myStatment = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            myStatment.clearParameters();

     myStatment.setString(1, service.toString());
     myStatment.setString(2, service.toString());
     myStatment.setString(3, ref);
     myStatment.setString(4, title); 
     myStatment.setString(5, riskRating.toString());
     myStatment.setString(6, rootCause.toString());
     myStatment.setString(7, impact.toString());
     myStatment.setString(8, likelihood.toString());
     myStatment.setString(9, efforts);
     myStatment.setString(10, finding);
     myStatment.setString(11, implication);
     myStatment.setString(12, recommendation);


            boolean myResult = myStatment.execute(); 


           System.out.println("done");


        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Information is missing or incorrect! Please Make sure to enter correct information");
            Logger.getLogger(Insert_info.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return;

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your information was saved successfully!");
```

Comment: Given that all these tables (apparently) have the same structure why are they separate tables?  Why should the user care which table stores their data?

Comment: This is one of the req. of the system .. how could I insert data it then.. ??

Comment: Would a viable alternative be to pass the table name, and all the other parameters, to a procedure that does the insert to the appropriate table, e.g. via a `case` on the passed table name string so only known (and thus presumably valid) tables names are recognised?

Comment: It is *not* a requirement.  It is an implementation detail.  Or at least it ought to be.  I concede that once somebody has built a shonky data model the rest of the application has to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into ?
```

You cannot use a bind variable for schema object names. The reason being that when you prepare the statement, the database needs to know what tables are involved, and decide which indexes to use, so the query SQL needs to be known (only the data can change).

So if you want to do this, you have to use string interpolation to construct the query (only for the table name, continue to use bind variables for the data!).

```
String query = "insert into "+ tableName + ....
```

Make sure that you validate this `tableName`. In your case, it can probably be checked against a HashSet of valid table names. Do not let this become an SQL injection problem.

Comment: I don't understand these words, could u give me more details : "Make sure that you validate this tableName. In your case, it can probably be checked against a HashSet of valid table names. Do not let this become an SQL injection problem."

Comment: And the sql statement should be like this :                    String query = "insert into" + service + "(Service,Ref,Title,Risk_Rating,Root_cause,Impact ,Likelihood,Efforts,Finding,Implication,Recommendation)values  ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?)";

Comment: You need to have code like `query = "insert into "+ tableName`. Make sure that this `tableName` is not direct user input. Validate it carefully. Read up on SQL injection. This is important.

Comment: Please Thilo could u please check my query ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing sintax:

```
String query = "insert into " &tablename "bla bla predicates"
```

To avoid the sql injection create roles in your databases and give access to the tables you want to be used by your visitors/users.

 Or you can use a wildcard :
Create a Variable tbl_name

```
String query = "insert into "(select table_name from user_tables where table_name like '%tbl_name%')"<br/>
```

- next create a decision "IF" and throw the output of the wildcard in it.If it matches the tables you have then ok if not treat it with an error message.